# C sockets client/server lag

Tags: c, sockets

I'm programming a C/C++ client/server sockets application. At this point, the client connects itselfs to the server every 50ms and sends a message.

Everything seems to works, but the data flow is not continuous: Suddenly, the server doesn't receives anything more, and then 5 messages at once... And sometimes everything works...

Has someone an idea of the origin of this strange behaviour ?

Some part of the code:

Client:

```
while (true)
{
if (SDL_GetTicks()-time>=50)
{
socket = new socket();
socket->write("blah");
message.clear();
message = socket->read();
socket->close();
delete socket;
time=SDL_GetTicks();
}
}
```

Server:

```
while (true) {
fd_set readfs;
struct timeval timeout={0,0};
FD_ZERO(&readfs);
FD_SET(sock, &readfs);
select(sock + 1, &readfs, NULL, NULL, &timeout)
if(FD_ISSET(sock, &readfs))
{
SOCKADDR_IN csin;
socklen_t crecsize = sizeof csin;
SOCKET csock = accept(sock, (SOCKADDR *) &csin, &crecsize);
sock_err = send(csock, buffer, 32, 0);
closesocket(csock);
}
}
```

**Edits:**
<s>1. I tried to do</s>

```
int flag = 1;
setsockopt(socket, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_NODELAY, &flag, sizeof flag);
```

In both client and server, but the problem is still there.

2.Yes those connections/deconnections are very inneficient, but when I try to write

```
socket = new socket();
while (true)
{
if (SDL_GetTicks()-time>=50)
{
socket->write("blah");
message.clear();
message = socket->read();
time=SDL_GetTicks();
}
}
```

Then the message is only sent once (or received)...

**Finally:**

I had forgotten to apply TCP_NODELAY to the client socket on the server side. Now it works perfectly !
I put the processes in threads so that the sockets keep open.
Thank you all :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is what called "[Nagle delay](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle's_algorithm)". This algorithm is waiting on TCP stack for more data to arrive before actually sending anything to network untill some timeout expires. So you should modify the Nagle timeout (http://fourier.su/index.php?topic=249.0) or disable Nagle delay at all (http://www.unixguide.net/network/socketfaq/2.16.shtml), so data will be sent per `send` call.

Comment: I am always fascinated by the knowledge of people here. Thank you very much. I will try that in a while :)

Answer (score 6):

As others already replied the delays you see are due to TCP built-in [Nagle algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle_algorithm), which can be disabled by setting `TCP_NODELAY` socket option.

I would like to point you to the fact that your socket communications are very inefficient due to constant connects and disconnects. Every time client connects to the server there's the [three way handshake](http://www.3wayhandshake.com/) that takes place, and connection tear-down requires four packets to complete. Basically you lose most of the benefits of TCP but incur all of its drawbacks.

It would be *much* more efficient for each client to maintain persistent connection to the server. `select(2)`, or even better, [`epoll(4)`](http://linux.die.net/man/4/epoll) on Linux, or [`kqueue(2)`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=kqueue&sektion=2) on FreeBSD and Mac, are very convenient frameworks for handling IO on multiple sockets.

Comment: Not just the handshake and teardowns, but every time you form a new connection you get to go through slow-start *again*.

Comment: @Klaus, you need to make those changes on both sides, not just client. As is the server closes each connection after first read. Also, TCP does not guarantee a single write to the socket to correspond to a single read on the other side. Both are usually done in a loop. Then your application protocol needs to validate the bytes received.

Answer (score 3):

You can use TCP_NODELAY socket option to force the data sending immediately.